# Creating multiple textFields using an array

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a 9x9 grid of textFields that are all in an array. The top left would be called fields[1][1] and the bottom right fields[9][9]. The code I've written so far is

```
    int NUM_FIELDS_X = 1; //x textField
    int NUM_FIELDS_Y = 1; // y textField
    int x = 21; // x location of textField
    int y = 21; // y location of textField

    TextField[][] fields = new TextField[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y]; {
        for (NUM_FIELDS_Y =1; NUM_FIELDS_Y <= 9; NUM_FIELDS_Y++) {

            for (NUM_FIELDS_X =1; NUM_FIELDS_X <= 9; NUM_FIELDS_X++) {

                    fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y] = new TextField();

                    fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y].setColumns(10);
                    fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y].setBounds(x, y, 32, 32);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y]);

                    x=x+32;
                }
            y = y+32;
        }
    }
```

However I'm getting an error as soon as I launch it, and the for loops do not start. The error message im receiving is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at sudokuSolver.sudokuInterface.initialize(sudokuInterface.java:70)
at sudokuSolver.sudokuInterface.<init>(sudokuInterface.java:44)
at sudokuSolver.sudokuInterface$1.run(sudokuInterface.java:31)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for the help Akash Jha and coder-croc, I've managed to fix it. I've changed the code to

```
    int NUM_FIELDS_X = 0; //x number of textField
    int NUM_FIELDS_Y = 0; // y number of textField
    int x = 21; // x location of textField
    int y=21; // y location of textField



    TextField[][] fields = new TextField[9][9]; {
        for (NUM_FIELDS_Y =0; NUM_FIELDS_Y < 9; NUM_FIELDS_Y++) {
            x=21;
            for (NUM_FIELDS_X =0; NUM_FIELDS_X <= 8; NUM_FIELDS_X++) {

                    fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y] = new TextField();

                    fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y].setColumns(10);
                    fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y].setBounds(x, y, 32, 32);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(fields[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y]);

                    x=x+32;
                }
            y = y+32;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, the top left would be `fields[0][0]` and the bottom right `fields[8][8]`.  Arrays are zero-based in Java.  Also, _" I'm getting an error"_ is insufficient. Would you take your car to be repaired and refuse to tell the mechanic the symptoms?  Please post the complete error message and stack trace by [edit]ing your question.  Format the stack trace as code.

Comment: @JimGarrison that's why i set both NUM_FIELDS_X and Y to 1 at the beginning, so it wouldn't be 0 - 8

Comment: That's not how array declaration works.  Please revisit the Java tutorial section on arrays.  You cannot change the origin index of an array, it is always ZERO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which has the problem,

```
NUM_FIELDS_Y = 1; NUM_FIELDS_Y <= 9;
```

Your array is from `fields[0][0]` to `fields[8][8]` for length 9 (*index 0 to 8*) and `NUM_FIELDS_Y <= 9` condition will be going to access `fields[9][9]` and thus you are getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Secondly, you are skipping the 0th index as `NUM_FIELDS_Y =1` will access `fields[1][1]` instead of `fields[0][0]`.

Change your loop,

```
int xLength = 9;
int yLength = 9;
TextField[][] fields = new TextField[xLength][yLength];
for (int x = 0; x < xLength; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < yLength; y++) { 
        // your code
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Your fields array has length `1`,

```
TextField[][] fields = new TextField[NUM_FIELDS_X][NUM_FIELDS_Y];
```

So `fields` can only have one 1 element at index `[0][0]` and first iteration is trying to access `[1][1]` which is incorrect.

Visit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) link to understand more about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of your text field as [1][1] and you are trying to put more than one element in your array...
Increase the size of your text field array. That will help

Comment: So should I change it to TextField[][] fields = new TextField[9][9]